# What is the name of this map and what does it do?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

I have found the following sentence and I am wondering about the meaning(what does this map do, as well as the name of this map g):
Let $M:=f^{-1}(c)$ be an embedded manifold of dimension n-m with tangent space $T_{z_0}M = \text{Kern } Df(z_0)$, that means a local graph of a function $g: T_{z_0}M \mapsto (T_{z_0}M)^\perp$.

Does anybody here have an idea, what is meant by $g$ in this context?

Comment: Implicit defined function theorem?

Comment: this sounds good, as the implicit function theorem is covered one page earlier. could you say a few words more about your suggestion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think "embedded manifold" refers to a manifold embedded into some Euclidean space $\mathbb R^n$. In this case $T_{z_0}M$ can be identified with a linear subspace of $\mathbb R^n$, namely the space of all vectors of the form $\gamma'(0)$ where $\gamma:(-1,1)\to M$ is smooth and $\gamma(0)=z_0$. The orthogonal complement of $T_{z_0}M$ is defined as usual. Every point $x\in \mathbb R^n$ has coordinates $(u,v)$ with $u\in T_{z_0}M$ and $v\in (T_{z_0}M)^{\perp}$.

The stated property is that some neighborhood of $z_0$ in $M$ can be written as $\{(u,v):v=g(u)\}$. This is easy to visualize when $M$ is a curve in a plane, which is locally the graph of a single-variable function.